# How to use an expression in an import with Babel + Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I have the following code in a TypeScript file:

```js
await import(`@resources/videos/${key}.mp4`)
  .then((mod) => mod.default)
  .catch((err) => console.error('failed to load tutorial', err))
```

This [should work](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import), however, it doesn't. I am using `babel-loader`, not `ts-loader`, but I still get the same issues whether I use TS or JS, and whether I use `preset-typescript` or not.

When I run Webpack, I get an error:
`Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`. Investigating further by compiling the code using the Babel CLI reveals that the expression I wrote above compiles to this:

```js
return Promise.resolve("@resources/videos/".concat(key, ".mp4")).then(function (s) {
  return _interopRequireWildcard(require(s));
}).then(function (mod) {
  return mod.default;
}).catch(function (err) {
  return console.error('failed to load tutorial', err);
});
```

It appears that Webpack is being tripped up by the fact that Babel is messing around with my string concatenation by converting it to a `.concat()` call and wrapping it in `Promise.resolve()`.

I tried to sidestep this by using ordinary concatenation instead of template literals, but that only changed Babel's output slightly:

```js
return Promise.resolve("".concat('@resources/videos/' + key + '.mp4')).then(function (s) {
  return _interopRequireWildcard(require(s));
}).then(function (mod) {
  return mod.default;
}).catch(function (err) {
  return console.error('failed to load tutorial', err);
});
```

**My setup:**

- Compiling TS and JS with `babel-loader` only, no `ts-loader`
- Babel presets: `env`, `typescript`,
- Babel plugins: `proposal-optional-chaining`, `proposal-class-properties`, `proposal-object-rest-spread`
- Babel version: `@babel/core` = 7.9.6
- Webpack version: 4.43.0

How do I make Babel stop doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by setting the `modules` option of `preset-env` to `false`.